# How do you know which branch that a newly created branch will be based off of?

Tags: git

Consider the following scenario:

I create a branch from master, and call that branch1 and create another commit for that branch (b). Then I create another branch without merging branch1 with master, using `git checkout -b branch2`.

A) How would I know which branch, branch2 would be based off of? Would it automatically create the branch off of the master branch or off of branch a?

B) How would you create a branch off of the branch that the first part didn't cover (i.e.: if the answer to first part is that that creates a branch off of branch1, how do you create a branch off of master/viceversa?)

```
 master --> a
                \
                 \
          branch1 --> b

         (location of new branch?)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git branch comes off your current branch (actually HEAD), by default.

If you want to specify where it branches from, specify the startpoint

```
git branch [--set-upstream | --track | --no-track] [-l] [-f] < branchname > [ <start-point> ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not create a branch from a branch but from a commit. And by default it is the commit you currently have checked out. If you want any other commit, just give it as argument to the `branch` command as you can read in its documentation.

Btw. to wrap your head around it, just consider branches and tags post-its that you stick onto an arbitrary commit, because that is exactly what branches and tags are in Git and nothing more. You can peel off the post-it at any time and stick it to another commit. In the case of branches this happens automatically if you have that branch checked out and create a new commit.